# Is there a cl or gcc option to treat "strings" as const wchar_t pointers rather than const char pointers?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, wchar-t, cl

I am looking for an option to treat "strings" in a C source unit as `const wchar_t*`, that is, the compiler should treat such strings as though they were prepended with an `L` (`L"strings"`).

As far as I can see, neither `cl` nor `gcc` have such an option, but I might have overlooked it when searching for it.

Thus my question, is there such an option (or maybe a preprocessor that does that?).

Comment: No, there is no sense in such, it would break EACH AND EVERY header in existence anyway.

Comment: Also, strings in C are not `const char *`, they're un-const character *arrays*.

Comment: While at it, why not have a compiler switch to convert all integers to double, or signed numbers to unsigned?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala mind you, I've seen the first request in some SO question ;-)

Comment: What you can *do* is to use the ugly trick that MS did and wrap all strings in a macro and *then* use a macro to control whether to paste `L` in front or not.

Comment: @MatteoItalia question or answer? :P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala question for sure, I don't want to know if there's any answer 